# Creating fields programmatically / with PlugIn

Tags: plugin-development, config

Anyone here who can provide a working sample of how to create several fields and groups using a plugin? It don't need to be fancy, nothing new, just re use the stuff thats built-in and it need to work somehow so I can extend it from there.

Is there something to consider if I create for example some profile fields for the Users Group? Or lets say I want a job portal and have field set name "job profile" which contains fields for job description, location, skills, ...

I feel a bit ashamed asking for such a comprehensive "task" but as I am not really a developer a lot things I am doing is hoping my try & error attempts succeed (sometime). Having said that, I am a real pro in destroying any environment to the ground and finding bugs but I am also very experienced in installing and configuring servers and apps - guess why this is...

This is the reason why I need to be able to create my playground as fast as possible and no, I don't want to copy/paste files, I want to learn extending the system.

Comment: I often make sites with 10-20 content blocks. I'd use Matrix field. For most of these fields I would have the same generic options, eg. dropdowns for bgcolor and textcolor options following the brand colors, padding top/bottom and mobile/desktop visibility. Making eg. 5 similar dropdowns across 20 blocks in the UI interface is not really a viable solution for me, and changing even the smallest details would be manual, slow and error prone. I was a little surprised that creating fields programmatically is not something Craft handles easily out of the box, given how extensive a system Craft is.

Comment: Hi there. This website isn't for Craft CMS feature requests, it's for folks in the community to help each other solve programming challenges. I'd recommend taking these questions to the Craft [Discord](https://craftcms.com/discord) channel if you'd like to discuss it further.

Comment: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions is also a good place to discuss new feature requests in Craft.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for recommendations. I've tried looking around for where to post suggestions, and it's not been very clear, so Thanks for pointing in the right direction.

In the meantime, however, I think it's still good to have the topic covered here as well, so any further comments on-topic are most welcome. I'm curious as to whether there's more people out there with the same thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at Craft's own [InstallController](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/controllers/InstallController) and [InstallService](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/InstallService) to see how Craft programmatically creates the default content you see during a fresh install.

Comment: Hi Brad - are there any simple working examples to get people started?